# Problems recognizing Ubuntu Minimal (for Kodi/XBMC) when installing Ubuntu 14.04 Regular Desktop

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, xbmc

my Goal: HTPC (2 Drives/ 1 minimal Ubuntu/1 Regular 14.04) dualbooting

Steps i am Trying :

A. Installing minimal Ubuntu Disk (XBMC/Kodi) /dev/sda

B. Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on /dev/sdb

Problem is when i Install 14.04 Desktop it doesnt recognize the minimal Installation .

"sudo update-grub" doesnt recognize the minimal Install even when sda Partitions are Mounted in Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop .....

What am i doing wrong ... ?

Thx in advance ...

Comment: What, in your case, would be the advantage of a dual-boot instead of a single boot having Kodi e.g. on a dedicated user account?

Comment: Problems with Passthrough (to ONKYO Reciever/5.1) audio on a dedicated xbmc/kodi account. Also I would like to install some "Services" on the xbmc/kodi drive that should not/can not not be in use on the Desktop!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Use the BIOS and give each OS one disk**

Each OS will have its own grub/system/data on their own disk...  Just Set the BIOS to boot from drive 1, install OS1. Then set the BIOS to boot from drive 2, install OS2.

To boot OS1, use the BIOS boot menu to boot from drive 1 (and the same for OS2/Drive2)

*Advantages:*

- Neither OS can mess up the other's boot/System/Data
- Even when one OS messes up its own boot, the BIOS can still boot from the other drive.

*Disadvantages:*

- To transfer data between OSes, you need to manually mount the other OS
- Takes up a lot of space

**Option 2: Dual boot from one system drive and one data drive**

Create two partitions and install OS1 in Partition 1, OS2 in partition 2. Use the second disk for file storage.

*Advantages:*

- More efficient space utilisation
- Only one boot manager to worry about

*Disadvantages:*

- Only one boot manager to mess up...

**Conclusion**

You've probably used option 1 (or something similar)